# QImage copy on write

Tags: qt, qimage, pimpl-idiom, copy-on-write, qshareddata

is `QImage` based on `QSharedData` ? Do `Qimage` follow `pimpl` or `copy on write` ?
e.g. would copying(through copy con or assignment) an Qimage make a deep copy of pixels ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QImage is copy on write. It will not copy pixels until you start modifying it.

For what it's worth when passing it into functions, I always use const QImage & anyway not to freak anyone out.

Comment: A reference to documentation that proves your statement would be highly desirable.

Comment: Late to the party, but [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#details) you can read that `QImage` uses implicit data sharing.